# My WPF UserControl must never get wider than the containing ButtonBar

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, width, bind

I have bound at top the Width of the UserControl to the Width of the ButtonGrid at top.

It does not work. I want my UserControl always that wide as the width of the ButtonGrid. The problem is loading documents with a long name > Sum(Width of 3 buttons) makes the UserControl as wide as the document name. Now imagine having document names with 100 chars or longer and you add documents the UserContol will bump and jump...

```
<UserControl x:Class="TBM.View.DocumentListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Behaviours="clr-namespace:FunctionalFun.UI.Behaviours"
             xmlns:Helper="clr-namespace:TBM.Helper"            
             mc:Ignorable="d"          
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"   
             Width="{Binding ElementName=ButtonGrid,Path=Width}"
             >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Helper:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
            Behaviours:MultiSelectorBehaviours.SynchronizedSelectedItems="{Binding SelectedDocumentViewModelList,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                                                 
            Width="Auto"
            Focusable="True"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Name="documentListBox"
            BorderThickness="1"                                                
            ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentList}"
            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=documentListBox,Path=HasItems, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DocumentName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>
        <UniformGrid  x:Name="ButtonGrid"         
            Grid.Row="1"
            Rows="1"                                           
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            >
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteDocumentCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Delete" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddDocumentCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Add" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Path=OpenDocumentCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Open" />           
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 2 stuff

1. Use horizontal alignment on user control to stretch
2. Set binding to MaxWidth same as Width binding

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Set horizontal alignment to WHAT. Set MaxHeight?? Why Height? I talk about WIDTH

Comment: Ok Binding to the ListBox the same way I did to the UserControl works when I add a document to the listbox BUT when I navigate forth/back in my Calendar DataGrid then the Document ListBox has again the width of longest ListboxItem :/

Comment: Did not understand last comment can you explain?

Comment: sure I can: 1. User HorizontAlighment="Stretch" ? why this? I do not want to stretch my UserControl, I have nowhere written that.

Comment: I've just set "HorizontalAlignment" to "Stretch" of UserControl! It works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the width of the ParentGrid(containing the control) to a fixed size, en then horizontal alignment to Stretch

Comment: The control which contains the UserControl is a DataGrid or the DataGridTemplateColumn to be precisely. I do not want to set fixed size because/AND maybe further buttons are added in future to the 3 existing buttons. Then the width must be the sum(width of 4 buttons)

Comment: In this case the DataGrid, when you add a button just change the size the DataGrid. But i am fairly new to WPF, so there are probably better ways ;)

Comment: lol... there are probably better ways! ;-) at the moment I set the UserControl to exactly 125 pixel and it works for 3 buttons. But not for further buttons, then I have to change 125 to ... etc... not maintainable ;-)

Comment: I've just set "HorizontalAlignment" to "Stretch" of UserControl! It works like a charm! Thanks!